How to validate that each value of 'IN' statement are present in the SQL query result?
I have a set of tableA



Name
City




Paulo
Rome


Rudy
Singapore


Ming
Singapore


Takeshi
Tokyo


Judy
Jakarta


Yuki
Tokyo


Steve
Singapore



I want to make sure that person from Berlin, Singapore, and Tokyo, all 3 of those cities are present in the table
I have this SQL query to check that each city is present
select a.*
from (
select *,
  row_number() over (partition by city ) as rn
from tableA
where city in (Berlin, Tokyo, Singapore)
) a
where rn = 1

With this query I can find out that at least 1 person from those countries is present, while actually there's none from Berlin. What I want is the query can validate that all of cities that in IN condition are present. It will return True if all of them is present and False if one of them is missing. Is it possible to do so? Suggestion for simpler query also appreciated.

You can join the cities.

You can compare count of cities in IN(...) and your query output rows count
select case when count(*)=3 then 'true' else 'false' end res
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by city order by name) as rn
  from tableA
  where city in ('Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Singapore')
) a
where rn = 1

res='false'
OR simpler
select case when count(*)=3 then 'true' else 'false' end res
from(
  select distinct city
  from tableA
  where city in ('Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Singapore')
) a

Example
With @jarlh suggestion
select case when count(distinct city)=3 then 'true' else 'false' end res
from tableA
where city in ('Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Singapore')

I can't check it on amazon-athena, but it's a beautiful solution!

You can even do count(distinct city)=3, and skip the subquey.

@jarlh, you can suggest this as a separate answer. It seems to me that this is the most elegant solution.

No need. It was your query slightly improved.

"but it's a beautiful solution" - it has a small problem - editing number of cities requires editing the count condition.

Perhaps, city list is dynamically generated by front-end and checkCount is one of parameters. Also, I think, simple case when query returns number of cities and front side compare this value with cities count in parameter list. query_result=CityList.Count

If the list of cities is the result of another query, we need to look at the context - the query may be completely different.

Thank you so much guys for the answers. all of them works for me.

You can determine cities that are missing from the data using left join with CTE containing the data for cities:
WITH cities(name) as (values 'Berlin', 'Tokyo', 'Singapore') -- define the cities 

select cities.name
from cities
left join tableA on cities.name = tableA.City
where tableA.Name is null;

Output
  name
--------
 Berlin



RIGHT JOIN the 3 cities.

Count the not-found ones.

If 0, return True, else return False.


select case when count(*) = 0 then 'True' else 'False' end 
from tableA
right join (values ('Berlin'), ('Tokyo'), ('Singapore')) c (city)
    on tableA.city = c.city
where tableA.city is null

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/BDa3ZlmC
